# How can the application that makes an indicator icon be identified?

Tags: indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can menu bars that require a right click be activated like Ubuntu versions <10.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184589/how-can-menu-bars-that-require-a-right-click-be-activated-like-ubuntu-versions)

It used to be possible to identify the application that was responsible for an indicator icon by right-clicking it and selecting the `About` option in Ubuntu 10.04.

How is the application identification for an indicator icon done now in 12.04?

See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/187521/89468) in [How does one find out which application is associated with an indicator icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185991/how-does-one-find-out-which-application-is-associated-with-an-indicator-icon)

Comment: I disagree with closing as a duplicate. This is asking how to identify an indicator's source -- whatever way it's done -- not how to re-enable the old right click behavior.

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards you wouldn't be able to tell because some mod cleared all the comments, but these are the same question. He went on a ranting roll and the goal of his question is not to find out how to do either. He just wants to do as his name suggests (Annoy). Now that the comments are deleted I'll look like a liar and a fool, but that's what it is.